# How to delete line between pattern and empty line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to delete all lines between a pattern and empty line in shell script,For example

```
# a simple host tree
[localhost.localdomain]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes
    load=true

[localhost.localdomain2]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes

[localhost.localdomain3]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes
#
```

I want to delete `[localhost.localdomain]` and following lines before empty line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do:

```
awk '/\[localhost.localdomain\]/ {f=1} !f; !NF {f=0}' file
# a simple host tree
[localhost.localdomain2]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes

[localhost.localdomain3]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes
#
```

---

Or you can change the `RS` so `awk` works with blocks like this:

```
awk -v RS=[ '!/localhost.localdomain\]/ {print (NR>1?RT:"")$0}' file
# a simple host tree

[localhost.localdomain2]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes


localhost.localdomain3]
    address 127.0.1.1
    use_node_name yes
#
```

Comment: how can i save that changes to source file

Comment: @kumaran With `awk` you do like this `awk 'code' file > tmp && mv tmp file`